# SQL Lead/Lag function in Excel Vba

Tags: sql, excel, vba, lag, lead

Is there any particular format to use SQL Lag/Lead function in excel. I have written the following sql query but it is throwing syntax error

```
sqlPivot = "SELECT [Type],[Year],[Value],Value-(LAG(Value , 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER 
            BY [Type],[Year]))FROM (" & sqlResult & ") ORDER BY [Type],[Year]"
```

The error is shown at Value-LAG() function part.

Comment: Value is a reserved word in ODBC - change it for [Value]? Does the query run correctly in SSMS?

Comment: @Caius Jard I have tried it in SSMS , it works as expected. I changed the Value to [Value] , i have even tried after changing the field name from Value still the query results in same error.

Comment: Put the exact error message

Comment: @Caius Jard `Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Syntax error(Missing Operator) in query expression '[Value]-LAG([Value],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [Type],[Year])'`

Comment: And the full SQL (use the debugger to inspect the value of the sqlPivot varaible)